# import org.apache.log4j.Classloader cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

IDE: Eclipse Juno, JDK: 1.6
Project: Java Application

```
import org.apache.log4j.Classloader;
```

gives the error

> "import org.apache.log4j.Classloader cannot be resolved".

import org.apache.log4j.Logger; is not showing any error.

log4j-1.2.6.jar is added to build a path from build configuration.

I am stuck with this problem. Please help me to go through it. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `org.apache.log4j.Classloader` class in any Log4J 1.x library but [`org.apache.log4j.Loader`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/helpers/Loader.html) hence the error.

Comment: Sorry, I was modifying and old project by someone else and found that import and it was showing error. I was in trouble to fix and run. BTW Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it should be import org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader; I have decompiled log4j with JD GUI and have a look on all the class's java codes. Thank you, when you said there is no class named ClassLoader there, I got the idea to look up all the classes rather than only being stuck with documentations.